# Cucumber tests with Guice DI not able to find Named annotations

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, cucumber, integration-testing, guice

I've been trying to add integration tests using Cucumber-Guice verion 7.11. I have the following directory setup

```kotlin
src/main/kotlin/
\_ com.mypackage.tests
   \_ api/ApiGatewayHttpClient.kt
   \_ cucumber
      \_ api
         \_ ApiInfraTestsModule.kt
      \_ CucumberInjectorSource.kt
      \_ InfraTestsModule.kt
   \_ steps
      \_ EdgeApiSteps.kt
```

The `ApiInfraTestsModule.kt` is written as follows:

```kotlin
class ApiInfraTestsModule : AbstractModule() {

    private val ROLE_ARN_FORMATTER = "arn:aws:iam::%s:role/%s"

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesCloudFormationExportsExtractor(): BiFunction<String, String, String> {
        return BiFunction { region: String, exportName: String ->
            // some CloudFormation logic, return export value
        }
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(EDGE_API_ENDPOINT)
    fun providesEdgeApiEndpoint(
        cloudFormationExportsExtractor: BiFunction<String, String, String>
    ): String {
        val region = Environment.region
        return cloudFormationExportsExtractor.apply(
            region, EDGE_API_ENDPOINT_EXPORT_NAME
        )
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(EDGE_API_UNAUTHORIZED_CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER)
    fun providesApiUnauthorizedCredentialsProvider(
        // this param is supposed to be injected via `InfraTestsModule.kt`
        awsCredentialsProvider: BiFunction<String, String, AwsCredentialsProvider>
    ): AwsCredentialsProvider {
        val region = Environment.region
        val roleArn = String.format(
            ROLE_ARN_FORMATTER,
            Environment.plantFloorAccountId,
            Environment.unauthorizedEdgeProvisioningRoleName
        )
        return awsCredentialsProvider.apply(region, roleArn)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(EDGE_API_UNAUTHORIZED_CLIENT)
    fun providesEdgeApiUnAuthorizedClient(
        @Named(EDGE_API_UNAUTHORIZED_CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER)
        credentialsProvider: AwsCredentialsProvider
    ): ApiGatewayHttpClient {
        return ApiGatewayHttpClient(
            Region.of(Environment.region),credentialsProvider
        )
    }
}
```

The `CucumberInjectSource.kt` is as follows:

```kotlin
class CucumberInjectorSource : InjectorSource {
    @ScenarioScoped
    override fun getInjector(): Injector {
        return Guice.createInjector(
            Stage.PRODUCTION,
            CucumberModules.createScenarioModule(),
            InfraTestsModule(),
            ApiInfraTestsModule()
        )
    }
}
```

And the `EdgeApiSteps.kt` is written as:

```kotlin
class EdgeApiSteps @Inject constructor(
    private val testContext: TestContext,
    @Named(EDGE_API_ENDPOINT)
    private val endpoint: String,
    @Named(EDGE_API_UNAUTHORIZED_CLIENT)
    private val unauthorizedApiClient: ApiGatewayHttpClient
) {

    @When("Provisioning API is called with unauthorized client")
    fun executeUnauthorizedApiCall() {
        val response = unauthorizedApiClient.get(endpoint)
        testContext.apiResponseStatus = response.httpResponse().statusCode()
    }
}
```

When I run these tests, the dependency injection fails for the Named annotation with the following error:

```
Failed scenarios:
file:////features/security/api/EdgeApi.feature:2 # Provisioning API call with unauthorized principal should fail

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
2 Steps (1 failed, 1 skipped)
0m0.663s


com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) [Guice/MissingImplementation]: No implementation for ApiGatewayHttpClient annotated with @Named(value="EdgeApiUnauthorizedClient") was bound.

Requested by:
1  : EdgeApiSteps.<init>(EdgeApiSteps.kt:11)
      \_ for 3rd parameter
     while locating EdgeApiSteps

Learn more:
  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/MISSING_IMPLEMENTATION

2) [Guice/MissingImplementation]: No implementation for String annotated with @Named(value="EdgeApi") was bound.

Requested by:
1  : EdgeApiSteps.<init>(EdgeApiSteps.kt:11)
      \_ for 2nd parameter
     while locating EdgeApiSteps

Learn more:
  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/MISSING_IMPLEMENTATION

2 errors
```

I have looked at a lot of Guice examples and it seems @Named injection is supported via Guice for Kotlin. But I've not been able to make this work at all. I'm not sure of Cucumber is not able to find the Guice modules. I even stripped down the modules to just provide a single @Named string parameter and that fails with the same "No implementation bound" error too.

I've tried constructor injection, method injection, field injection to the above class and none of this has led to anything but the above error.

Comment: How did you tell Cucumber to use your custom injector?

Comment: Through `cucumber.glue=com.mypackage.tests` property defined inside `src/main/resource/cucumber.properties` file.

Comment: Can you also show your InjectorSource

Comment: @Alexey R. Added above. Does this look like a misconfiguration specific to Cucumber-Guice version 7?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious that is wrong in your code. But at this point the layer between Guice and Cucumber isn't very thick either. Could you put some breakpoints in the `GuiceFactory` and `GuiceBackend` and see what happens?

Comment: Also if this is a bug in Cucumber that you can reproduce in a minimal example, please file a bug report. You can use https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton as a base.